# Name Hiding vs OVERRIDE

Tags: c#, .net, oop

When would you implement name hiding over the override keyword?
As the functionality provided using name hiding can be achieved using the override keyword?

Comment: Simply _never_ use name hiding. Instead, choose an unused name for the new member of the derived class. Name collisions can happen by accident if the provider of the base class is another company or something, and they release a new version of their library. In that case you can put in a `new` keyword to acknowledge that you are aware of the problem. Remember: Hiding does ***not*** remove the hidden member. It can stil be used (when ever a reference to the object has the compile-time type of the base class). That leads to confusion. So avoid name hiding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is method hiding ever a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663274/is-method-hiding-ever-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you needed to *override* a member that wasn't `virtual`. The `override` keyword is for `virtual` or `abstract` members.

If it's a `virtual` member, then prefer to `override` instead of *hide* because when you `override` you can still execute the `base`.

Answer (score 2):

`override` and `new` are *not* equivalent, and do not provide the same functionality.

Take, for instance these classes.

```
public class Herple
{
    public virtual void DoTheVirtualHerple()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Virtual Herple!");
    }

    public void DoTheHerple()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Herple!");
    }
}

public class Derple : Herple
{
    public override void DoTheVirtualHerple()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Actually I'd prefer to Derple!");
    }

    public new void DoTheHerple()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Let's Derple instead!");
    }
}
```

When assigning a `Derple` instance to a variable of type `Herple` the behavior of which concrete method is invoked changes based on whether or not the method is overridden or hidden. e.g.:

```
var herpleList = new List<Herple> {new Herple(), new Derple()};

foreach (var curple in herpleList)
{
    curple.DoTheVirtualHerple();
    curple.DoTheHerple();
}
```

prints:

Virtual Herple!
Herple!
Actually I'd prefer to Derple!
Herple!

To your original question, as to when you'd prefer name hiding to overriding, in general you *wouldn't* prefer it, but if you're extending classes from an API you aren't responsible for, it may be your only option. You should, however, be aware that your logic will never be invoked in any case where the base class is used, and plan accordingly, and verify that your design is actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

If your method in base class is not `virtual` or `abstract` then you have no other option but to hide it. Also remember if you don't use the keyword `new` with method hiding you will get a warning.

[new Modifier (C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/435f1dw2.aspx)

> You can hide members without using the new modifier, but the result is
>   a warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, the modifier
>   suppresses this warning and documents the fact that the derived
>   version is intended as a replacement.

You may also see: [What's the difference between override and new? - Jon Skeet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-override-code-and-code-new-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Virtual()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Virtual A");
    }

    public void NameHidding()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name Hidding A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Virtual()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Override B");
    }

    public new void NameHidding()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name Hidding B");
    }
}
```

If the object's data type is B:

```
        B b = new B();
        b.Virtual();
        b.NameHidding();
```

Prints:
Override B
Name Hidding B

But if we define the data type of the object as A:

```
        A b = new B();
        b.Virtual();
        b.NameHidding();
```

Prints:
Override B
Name Hidding A

Relationship with polymorphism.