# Shadowing in c# - base method gets called instead of derived

Tags: c#, oop, shadowing

I'm trying to figure out the concept of shadowing in c#. This is my code, which isn't behaving as I expect it to:

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo Animal");
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public new void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo Dog");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        ((Animal)dog1).Foo();
        Animal dog2 = new Dog();
        dog2.Foo();
    }
}
```

When the code in `Main` is executed, `Foo()` from the base class (`Animal`) is called, and from what I read about shadowing, `Foo()` from `Dog` should be called. Can someone explain what am i missing?

My example is according to this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

UPDATE:
This is the example from msdn:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
        BaseClass bcdc = new DerivedClass();

        // The following two calls do what you would expect. They call
        // the methods that are defined in BaseClass.
        bc.Method1();
        bc.Method2();
        // Output:
        // Base - Method1
        // Base - Method2


        // The following two calls do what you would expect. They call
        // the methods that are defined in DerivedClass.
        dc.Method1();
        dc.Method2();
        // Output:
        // Derived - Method1
        // Derived - Method2


        // The following two calls produce different results, depending 
        // on whether override (Method1) or new (Method2) is used.
        bcdc.Method1();
        bcdc.Method2();
        // Output:
        // Derived - Method1
        // Base - Method2
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Method1");
    }

    public virtual void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Method2");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method1");
    }

    public new void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method2");
    }
}
```

When `bcdc.Method1()` is executed, `Method1()` from the derived class gets called, which isn't the case in my example.

Comment: Which exact bit makes you expect that the `Foo()` method from `Dog` would be called? In both cases, you're calling it via an expression with a compile-time type of `Animal`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: new versus override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/c-new-versus-override)

Comment: The `Car`/`ConvertibleCar`/`Minivan` shows exactly what you are trying to do. Same page.

Comment: The point is, if you want a method call to go to an overridden method, you need an uninterrupted chain of `virtual`/`override`. `new` interrupts this chain.

Comment: This shows that in most cases, shadowing/hiding is a spawn of Evil incarnate that should never have been: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663274/is-method-hiding-ever-a-good-idea for situations where it can be used (to make up for another shortcoming in the language)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `dog1` which is a `Dog` will usually get you "Foo Dog", but because you explicitly tell it to be an `Animal`, it displays the "Foo Animal". Makes sense.

Then, with the `dog2`, which is an `Animal`, you expect the "Foo animal" to fire, because you said "hey, you're an animal", and even though you have `virtual` on `Animal` (which suggests that deriving classes should override this method, and then the resolution of what to call will happen on run time depending on the type), you use the `new` which hides it.

---

Still perfectly Ok. In their example, `bcdc` is of type `BaseClass`, but at runtime , since it's a `Derived` one, AND `Method1` is using `virtual` AND `override`, on the base and derived, it gets called.

Because it's `method2` isn't overriding the virtual, it calls the only one it knows about, the **Base** one. If instead of defining it as `BaseClass`, it would have been a `DerivedClass`, it would have found it's `method2`

Answer (score 0):

In your example when you do `((Animal)dog1).Foo()` or `dog2.Foo()`, Foo method of Animal gets executed because when you run the application CLR first search the implementation in base(because of the reference to Animal) and then checks if it overridden in derived type or not, as You have not overridden the base class implementation it is calling the base method(Animal's Foo) instead of derived(Dog's Foo) in both the case.

UPDATE :

There is very small difference between override and new keyword.
When you do override, does not matter which reference you are using it always calls overridden method when the object is of Derived type.
In case of new keyword you are not doing overriding, you are actually hiding the base class implementation
I meant here is you are hiding the implementation of base class for Derived type not for the base, so when you use reference of base for derived object like
`Base obj = new Derived();`
it always calls base method because it can not find the overridden method in derived.

Comment: It's executing derived class method because you have override the Method1.

Comment: I have also updated my answer, I hope this will answer your question.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the line, `((Animal)dog1).Foo()`, first the object dog1 will be converted to type Animal from Dog. So it calls the method in base class Animal.

If you use **override** instead of the **new** keyword in the **Foo** method of dog class, you will get your expected result (i.e, **Foo** method of **Dog** class will be called).

In your code `Animal dog2 = new Dog();`, dog2 will be created as an object of `Animal` instead of `Dog`. So, calling the `Foo` method will invoke the method in `Animal` class.

You can call the **Foo** method in **Dog** class by using the following code `((Dog)dog2).Foo();`. Here conversion from `Animal` to `Dog` class is possible because the variable `dog2` is originally created from the **constructor of Dog class**